# Show that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}{\sqrt x}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$ by using $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to do integration by parts to be able to use $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$, but is not working.

Comment: Try the substitution $u^2=x$.

Answer (score 1):

First do an integration by parts to get $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2\sqrt{x}}$, then try the substitution $u = \sqrt{x}$. It would be easier this way.

Comment: It worked! I had tried this before for some reason had failed. Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=u^2$. Then $dx=2udu$ and then the integral becomes

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}u(2udu)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}2e^{-u^2}u^2du$$

Then you can use integration by parts to get

$$u^2|_0^\infty \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du-\int\limits_0^\infty 4e^{-u^2}udu$$

and you will plug in the values and use integration by parts again. I think you can take if from here.